# Charging Nexus 5 to 100%

Tags: charging, battery-life, nexus-5

Is it wrong to fully charge your android phone in general to 100% will it hurt battery life? and is it also to drain your battery to below 20% will it also hurt the battery life?

Comment: Answers to this you will find in our [charging tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/charging/info). Other questions you might wish to see: [Does constant charging harm my Android cellphone?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/1020/16575) / [When should I start charging my Lithium battery?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/4003/16575) / [How frequently is it okay to let the battery discharge fully or as low as possible?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/33704/16575)

Answer (score 0):

As derived from this [battery-related answer:](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/3000/59496)

Li-ion batteries, unlike former battery technologies, do **not** need full discharges - actually, it's better if you don't let them drop below 40% (it's kind of like a sweet spot for batteries; you'll age your battery if you store it below 40%). It's also [unhealthy](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/1023/59496) for the battery to be left at 100%, that's why a number of phones (Nexus devices, to be exact) [quickly drain](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/35393/59496) the battery down to something like 98% or 95% after you unplug the charger.